# URL to link, without touching html element (href, text)

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have this string

```
$message = "http://world.com<br><br>www.bb.ru<br><a href='http://go.com/mod' target='_blank'>http://go.com/</a>";
```

and this code

```
$message = preg_replace('|((https?://)?([\d\w\.-]+\.[\w\.]{2,6})[^\s\]\[\<\>]*/?)|i', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $message);
$message = preg_replace('|\B#([\d\w_]+)|i', '<a href="http://url.com/pluslink/$1">$0</a>', $message);
$message = preg_replace('|\B\+([\d\w_]+)|i', '<a href="http://url.com/pluslink/$1">$0</a>', $message);
```

out of it

```
<a href="http://world.com">http://world.com</a><br>
<a href="www.bb.ru">www.bb.ru</a><br>
<a href="<a href=&quot;http://go.com/mod" "="">http://go.com/mod'</a> target='_blank'><a href="http://go.com/">http://go.com/</a>
```

How do I get the code to ignore a ellement.

the result would be

```
<a href="http://world.com">http://world.com</a><br>
<a href="www.bb.ru">www.bb.ru</a><br>
<a href='http://go.com/mod' target='_blank'>http://go.com/</a>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _ignore element_? Please be a little more specific with this question.

Comment: Never mind, got it. Answering...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore the element `<a>`, just try to cut it from the string first, then append to it in the end. You can try to accomplish it with this:

```
$orig = $message;
preg_replace("/<a(.*)<\/a>/i", "", $message);
// execute text manipulative functions to your will
preg_match("/<a(.*)<\/a>/i", $orig, $matches);
$links = "";
foreach ($matches as $current) {
    $links .= $current."\n";
}
$message .= $links;
```

**Note:** The `i` at the end ignores the case.